# Which document type definition we need to use in html?

Tags: html, dtd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the different doctypes in html and what do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255470/what-are-the-different-doctypes-in-html-and-what-do-they-mean)
>   [HTML DTDs - what's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266562/html-dtds-whats-the-point)

there are different types of DTD like strict, transitional and etc., which DTD is mostly used in common and why?

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev: I see there are lot of DTD's i just want to know the difference. I can understand that there are schemas but i just want to know which one is used mostly?

Comment: According to the W3C specs, different DTDs include different features. For example, if you want to use <font> in your webpage, you'll use the Transitional doctype. If you want to use <ruby>, you'll use XHTML 1.1, etc. In practice though, it doesn't matter, because all browsers support features no matter what Doctype declaration you have. As long as you use one; don't leave it out altogether!

Answer (score 0):

The most recent html5-compatible doctype you can use is simply:

```
<!doctype html>
```

This should be compatible with all modern browsers.

For HTML4 document, it doesn't really matter. I used to choose Transitional.

Comment: How do you figure "it doesn't really matter" for HTML 4? The DTDs imply different things; you should use the one that is most appropriate for your page.

Answer (score 0):

What is  a DOCTYPE:

> A Document Type Declaration, or DOCTYPE, is an instruction that
>   associates a particular SGML or XML document (for example, a webpage)
>   with a Document Type Definition (DTD) (for example, the formal
>   definition of a particular version of HTML).

**Why we need  a DOC type:**

If you do not declare a specific doctype correctly a visitors browser must "guess" (usually by applying the loosest possible doctype or a "quirks" mode doctype of its own) resulting in slower rendering.

[Comparison of document types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types)

[Transitional vs. Strict Doctypes](http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup)

Answer (score -1):

We mostly use this DTD only...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Check the following link if you have any doubts

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: That's a terrible doctype to use. It (a) doesn't give standards mode in browsers; (b) When served as `text/html` (as it almost invariably is), causes browsers to see the mark-up in a completely different way to validators, making it harder than necessary to know if your validated mark-up will actually work in a browser; and (c) was created over 10 years ago to aid *transition* towards the proper standard. You really shouldn't need to be still transitioning now.

Comment: And by the way, around here it's unwise to refer to W3Schools as any sort of authority, and *especially* to do with XHTML as they don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: It's not just XHTML where they don't know what they're talking about... http://w3fools.com/