# CSS breaks in Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, wordpress

This Wordpress site works fine in Firefox and Safari.

However viewing in Explorer 7 (don't care about 6) breaks the header/navigation area.

Weirdly enough, refreshing the page fixes the alignment issue, but then hides the header.

http://anothersideof.me

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a post for http://Doctype.com

Comment: As this is still a programming question I am going to leave it open here. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is fix your code errors:
[[Invalid]Markup Validation of  anothersideof.me  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//anothersideof.me/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Then look into the differences in doctypes: [What are the different doctypes in html and what do they mean? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255470/what-are-the-different-doctypes-in-html-and-what-do-they-mean) and how they work with IE.