# Rules for doctypes

Tags: html, css

After going through a lot of articles and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255470/what-are-the-different-doctypes-in-html-and-what-do-they-mean), **i know Why doctypes are used for** and also about the different modes triggered by the browser like standards, quirks etc.

I downloaded the a strict doctype from this url - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd but couldn't understand a thing of what is written inside it.

My question is, if i want to write a page with html and css which is going to have a doctype that will trigger standards mode, where can i get a **clear and simple to understand** list of **all the rules** that my html and css code should adhere to?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the W3C specification. That should tell you a lot. It should also have well-written and well-documented code, which adheres to web semantics. Develop your own patterns which you use and after experience it will become more adherant.

A few things that I would suggest, is making sure your `meta`, `br` and `link` tags don't have `/>` at the end of them.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- bad -->
<link rel="stylesheet"> <!-- good -->
```

Also, don't put `div`s with `id`s inside of `div`s with `class`es.

```
<div class="myClass"> <!-- bad -->
    <div id="myId">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="myId"> <!-- good -->
    <div id="myClass">

    </div>
</div>
```

Also, be wary of deprecated elements. Google "deprecated html elements" and you will find a lot of references. For example, don't use HTML tags which *style* content, only use HTML tags which *format* content, then use CSS to style it. (E.g. the *i, b, s, u, font* tags).

"Standards", is also a very broad "umbrella" topic. There are many ways which you can comply or not comply to standards. Also, try to always stick to HTML5 and CSS3 semantics, see [this page](http://w3.org/html5) for info on that.

Some good references:

http://www.w3.org/html5
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/
http://www.webkit.org/coding/coding-style.html (only for a few things)
http://www.w3.org/standards/

## Edit

*in response to your confused comment*

Well, you don't really *have* to avoid closing statements ( `/>` ), it's just [good practice](http://webdesignledger.com/tips/html5-essentials-and-good-practices). 
So it's not critical or even eligible for criticism that you avoid it, it's just all about forming good, structural and adherent-to-standard habits. And those
are just a few things I pointed out, not even a big deal. Those are just things that I correct
if re-designing a website.

As far as the nesting scheme, it is, again, considered good practice. Think about it, `id` stands
for identification. It identifies parts of your document. A `div` with a `class` in it, defines
a certain class or target for certain elements that are more pointed. What would you be doing
identifying a large part of your document inside of an element that's meant to target a specific
part of your document? I like to think of it as a parent-child relationship, however this
is quite debatable.

All in all, I suppose using the terms "good" and "bad" may have been a bit harsh. Replace them
with "what standard-wary people prefer" and "what standard-wary people don't prefer".

Going back to your question, it seems that my answer doesn't provide a list of **exact** 
rules, but I don't think such exists. Just worry about building good habits, and read up on
a lot of blogs and specs. Do some googling, you'll be surprised.

## Edit 2

On a second note, I see you're using HTML4 "Strict". This isn't 2009 anymore. Even though HTML5 is still only a candidate recommendation, if you're worried about adhering to the "latest and future standards", start sticking with it.

Comment: Also, you can use alot of JavaScript libraries such as Modernizr to detect older features which do not adhere to standards, then use polyfills or shims.

Comment: Your two suggestions don't make sense to me. Why would `/>` be bad? It's not like it's invalid syntax or anything in HTML5. Why should an element with an ID not be inside an element with a class? That severely limits where you can assign IDs to elements for no real reason at all.

Comment: XHTML 1.0 is a technological cul-de-sac, it expresses HTML 4.01 in XML but to use it on the WWW you have to pretend it is HTML and not XML (which involves jumping through some silly hoops). HTML 4.01 is a much better choice than XHTML 1.0.

Comment: I have never thought about that before. Moreover, HTML 4.01 "Strict" is out of date if you're going to worry about the latest "standards". Good point though, never thought about that.

Comment: HTML 4.01 is the latest "standard" for HTML. HTML 5 is still only a Candidate Recommendation.