# How can I make a Venn Diagram with values inside each component using SVG, CSS, or Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

I am trying to recreate this diagram in pure SVG (most preferred method), CSS, or through a Canvas (least preferred option). So far I can create 3 overlapping circles and add a value in the center of each. But when I go to add values to their intersecting parts I run into some troubles. I also do not know the logic to put text outside the venn diagram.

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" fill="red" />
<circle cx="220" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />
<circle cx="160" cy="180" r="80" fill="blue" />
<text x="100" y="100" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">A</text>
<text x="220" y="100" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">B</text>
<text x="160" y="180" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">C</text>
<path d="M 180,20 A 80,80 0 0,1 260,100 L 220,100 A 40,40 0 0,0 180,60 Z" fill="purple" />
<path d="M 140,100 A 80,80 0 0,1 180,60 L 140,60 A 40,40 0 0,0 100,100 Z" fill="orange" />
<path d="M 220,100 A 80,80 0 0,1 180,60 L 220,60 A 40,40 0 0,0 260,100 Z" fill="green" />
<text x="170" y="40" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">A ∩ C</text>
<text x="130" y="100" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">A ∩ B</text>
<text x="210" y="100" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">B ∩ C</text>
<text x="160" y="140" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">A ∩ B ∩ C</text>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. It looks like the SVG should be a static image, so try to statically position the values above the intersections. Should the "outside" text be part of the SVG image, then you need to contain them in the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SVG image

**Sidenote**: [SVG is XML-based](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/#abstract); this is [unlike HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16186093/13561410). As such, SVG's [attribute syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-attrval) requires quoted values, whereas in HTML5 [unquoted attribute value syntax](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#unquoted) is allowed.
Browsers may *occasionally* fix this syntax error, but this caused me a headache in the past.

Always specify an SVG's namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`). If you don't, the image may be recognized (and therefore rendered) incorrectly.

Also, always make sure to contain your graphics inside the visible region defined by the [`viewBox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox). Anything outside the `viewBox` will be clipped and therefore invisible.

### Venn diagram

The diagram appears to be static, so the elements can be positioned statically too. We won't have to worry about e.g. animations moving the elements outside the `viewBox`.

Simply position and colorize the [`<circle>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) and [`<text>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) within the `viewBox`.

I used [`<g>` (group) elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) to specify attributes that are inherited by default, to avoid duplicating the attributes on each element.

My SVG relies on some CSS to colorize the intersections. I chose this over more verbose alternatives:

- Using [`<clipPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) and the [`clip-path` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path) to "cut out" intersections,
- Using [`<path>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path) to represent all circle segments individually,
- Or other ways.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="600" viewBox="-2 -2 4 4"
    style="background-color: white">
  <g fill-opacity=".6">
    <circle cx="-.5" cy=".577" r="1"
        fill="darkorange" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply" />
    <circle cx=".5" cy=".577" r="1"
        fill="darkturquoise" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="-.33" r="1"
        fill="darkmagenta" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply" />
  </g>
  
  <g fill="white"
      font-size=".4" font-family="sans-serif"
      text-anchor="middle"
      dominant-baseline="hanging">
    <text y=".1">40</text>
    
    <text x="-1" y=".5">82</text>
    <text x="1" y=".5">88</text>
    <text y="-1">90</text>
    
    <text y=".8">58</text>
    <text x=".6" y="-.25">52</text>
    <text x="-.6" y="-.25">64</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Adding outside text

The labelling texts for the circles (i.e. "PR", "Ki67", "ER") need to be within the `viewBox` to be visible. In this case, the `viewBox` needs to be wider to contain them.

For the title (i.e. "% of Positivity") simply position it at the top left of the `viewBox`. You should also repeat its text in a [`<title>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title) to add an accessible name.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="600" viewBox="-2.5 -2 5 4"
    font-size=".4" font-family="sans-serif"
    style="background-color: white">
  <title>Percentage of Positivity</title>
  <text x="-2.5" y="-1.925"
      dominant-baseline="hanging"
      fill="gray">% of Positivity</text>

  <g fill-opacity=".6">
    <g fill="darkorange">
      <circle cx="-.5" cy=".577" r="1" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply" />
      <text x="-2.3" y=".5">PR</text>
    </g>
    <g fill="darkturquoise">
      <circle cx=".5" cy=".577" r="1" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply" />
      <text x="1.6" y="1.3">Ki67</text>
    </g>
    <g fill="darkmagenta">
      <circle cx="0" cy="-.33" r="1" style="mix-blend-mode:multiply" />
      <text x="1.2" y="-.5">ER</text>
    </g>
  </g>
  
  <g fill="white"
      text-anchor="middle"
      dominant-baseline="hanging">
    <text y=".1">40</text>
    
    <text x="-1" y=".5">82</text>
    <text x="1" y=".5">88</text>
    <text y="-1">90</text>
    
    <text y=".8">58</text>
    <text x=".6" y="-.25">52</text>
    <text x="-.6" y="-.25">64</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Note**: I moved the text-related attributes `font-family` and `font-size` to a common ancestor (`<svg>`) to be inherited by the new `<text>` elements.

---

You can specify the SVG's preferred size with the [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width) and [`height` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/height). If one is specified, the other is set implicitly to match the aspect-ratio of the `viewBox`.

## Embedding images in HTML

In HTML, you can [embed SVG images directly, or as an external resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66720422/13561410) with the [`<img>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

When embedded as an external resource, the browser only *renders* the SVG as an image. That means its content is translated into *visual-only* information, losing e.g. its texts and title.

As such, make sure to:

- [Provide a text alternative](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#alt) for the image with the [`alt` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#alt).
- Optionally add the preferred size again with the `width` and `height` attributes. Prefer this to avoid [layout shifting](https://web.dev/cls/).
- Optionally add a title to the image with the [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title). Ideally, this should match the SVG `<title>`'s content.

Example of embedding an SVG with an `<img>` element:

```html
<img width="600" height="480"
    src="/percentage-of-positivity.svg"
    title="Percentage of Positivity"
    alt="82% in PR, 88% in Ki67, 90% in ER.
58% between PR and Ki67, 52% between Ki67 and ER, 64% between ER and PR.
40% between PR, Ki67 and ER.">
```

You may want to be conscious about your use of white-space in the `alt` attribute, in case you want to preserve it (see CSS [`white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)).

**To add a caption** for the image, use the [`<figcaption>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption):

```css
/*<figure> and <figcaption> can also be styled!*/
figure {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  padding: .4rem;
}
figcaption:first-child {margin-block-end: .4rem}
figcaption:last-child {margin-block-start: .4rem}
figure>:not(figcaption) {background-color: #eee}

img[alt] {white-space:pre-line}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="/percentage-of-positivity.svg"
      title="Percentage of Posivity"
      alt="82% in PR, 88% in Ki67, 90% in ER.
58% between PR and Ki67, 52% between Ki67 and ER, 64% between ER and PR.
40% between PR, Ki67 and ER.">
  <figcaption>Percentage of positivity in PR, ER and Ki67 shown in a Venn diagram</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**Note**: Titles and captions are not the same! Think of a title as a short name, and of a caption as a short description.

Comment: Perfect thank you. Not sure why the question is closed/flagged when this answer solves the problem.