# Margin sometimes work sometimes don't under different doctype

Tags: css, margin

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<style>
    td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<p>
    1233
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>Some text</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I use `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">`, the `margin` of `<p>` and `<h3>` does not work, but if I use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, the `margin` works.

What's more, when I add

```
h3 {
    margin: 25px 0;
}
```

to the style, the `margin` of them suddenly works even using `HTML 4.0` doctype!

Why does this strange behavior happen? IE and Chrome behave the same on this issue, is this by design or something, it really confuse me.

I have a lot of pages written depend on this strange behavior, when I brought some CSS from other new components they defined margin then suddenly all these old pages broke. So I want to know what really happened.

Comment: wrong doctype.. should end with dtd

Comment: @airi Adding `"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"` yields the same result.

Comment: read this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255470/what-are-the-different-doctypes-in-html-and-what-do-they-mean

Comment: @airi OK, when I use `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 //EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`, the margin works. So it seems to be by design.

Comment: The code posted has no `margin` settings (except in the “What’s more” part). And “does not work” is not a problem description. Show an example that actually demonstrates the issue, and state the issue (e.g., specifying which `margin` setting has no effect even though it should).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The margin in the first part comes from the browser, if you use F12 to inspect, you can see margin.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I have a lot of pages written depend on this strange behavior, when I brought some CSS from other new components they defined margin then suddenly all these old pages broke. So I want to know what really happened.

Comment: You should clarify the question by editing the question itself. It should be understandable to future visitors as such, without peeking at comments (or answers).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela sure, added to the description.

Comment: What you added does not clarify the question; it does not help at all to se *what the question is about*. You seem to be referring to the presence or absence of *default* margins for some elements in some contexts, but you don’t say which elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the suppression of *default* top margins in some contexts in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html). Thus, if you use Quirks Mode for some reason (and working with legacy pages is often a very good reason), you should explicitly set any vertical margins you want to have for elements. The other solution is to move away from Quirks Mode, slapping `<!doctype html>` at the very start, but this may completely ruin (or maybe just disturb a little) your pages, if they have been created so that their rendering relies on buggy behavior and oddities in browsers.

The issue can be demonstrated with a simple standalone document (with no CSS):

```
<!doctype html>
<p>
    1233
</p>
<table border>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>Some text</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is empty space, about one empty line, at the beginning before “123” as well as inside the cell before “Some text”. If `<!doctype html>` is removed, that spacing disappears (but other margins are retained).

The issue is well described in section [10.3.10 Margin collapsing quirks](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#margin-collapsing-quirks) in HTML5 CR: “In quirks mode, any element with default margins [such as p or h3] that is the child of a body, td, or th element and has no substantial previous siblings is expected to have a user-agent level style sheet rule that sets its 'margin-top' property to zero.”

This feature relates to the browser tradition of suppressing top margins in contexts where they are normally useless or even disturbing. For example, if a heading element or a p element is the very first element in document body, or in a table cell, there is no need to separate it from the preceding content. The practice predates general availability of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm don't really know what hapening but, thats what you see in chrome at HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" is not real margins  it's a some browser initial styles you can see them in chrome dev tools: -webkit-margin-before, and -webkit-margin-after; this styles ovverides by margin.

For more information you better read specs on W3C, and use doctype html, or maybe html 4.0 strict.

Comment: I've searched a lot, all I got is something called "collapsing margin", they say adding 1px padding to the parent will undo, but I applied 5px to the td and the margin still "collapse"

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

I'm think initial browser margins, have a strange behavior (and different crossbrowser values) in transitional doctype, that's why every body use resets.

Looks like browser can't set clearence to table, tr, td :(

Comment: Maybe I had to just live with it.