# I need help in understating that, if I change the <!DOCTYPE> in the html page, will it affect some other functionality

Tags: html, xhtml

Current DOCTYPE:

```
        "!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

Required DOCTYPE:

```
        "!DOCTYPE HTML"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the different doctypes in html and what do they mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255470/what-are-the-different-doctypes-in-html-and-what-do-they-mean)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, some browsers will display documents without a system identifier (i.e. without the DTD part) in quirks mode. So those browsers may show a difference after changing to a proper one, yes.

Comment: Thanks @MrListerhana , Right now i'm developing some Web Application, i saw some changes in alignment after changing XHTML to HTML 5 Doc-type. So is there any possibility to give error while reading DATA from back-end.

Answer (score -1):

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd >

is to tell the browser that the document is XHTML 1.0

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

is to tell the browser that this document uses HTML5, the latest version of HTML available, also a 'living standard' from w3c

It is perfectly fine to change it, as HTML5 continue to support the older function. 
(Just like 'opening a word 2003 file .doc' with Microsoft Word 2007)

Comment: Thanks @Kristian. By changing will it effect in reading data from back-end. like from .JS or .XML file

Comment: It shouldn't. It just tell the browser after all. Nothing should change.