# Using HTML5 DOCTYPE and olderversion of markup language

Tags: html, doctype

I am planning to use HTML5 DOCTYPE.
But i may use some HTML4 or XHTML markups.
Will it be a valid to use HTML5 DOCTYPE? Will webpage will not go to Quirks Mode?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate? Anyways this should help you out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570418/if-i-use-html-5s-doctype-what-will-happen

Comment: I don't get it. If you're going to write XHTML 1.0 markup, why not use the XHTML 1.0 DOCTYPE?

Answer (score 1):

> Will it be a valid to use HTML5 DOCTYPE?

It is possible to write a document that (aside from the Doctype) is valid HTML 4 and valid HTML 5. It is also possible to write one that isn't. So "it depends".

> Will webpage will not go to Quirks Mode?

Browser rendering modes are not determined by anything after the Doctype (except for IE-specific meta tags).