# Are There Any Pros to Use HTML 5 Doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` Without Using HTML 5 Tags?

Tags: html, xhtml, cross-browser, cross-platform

Are there any pros to use the HTML 5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`, even if I am not using any new HTML 5 tags? Are there any benefits to replacing the XHTML doctype with the HTML 5 doctype, even if I am not using any new HTML 5 tags?

Can the HTML 5 doctype create problems in terms of functionality if I am using anything XML related with my site, or using HTML 5 for web development with any A-Grade browser? Is it supported in all desktop and mobile browsers?

Or, for right now, is it good to stick with the XHTML Doctype until 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any pros to use HTML 5 doctype  even if i'm not using any new HTML 5 tag?

Slightly less typing.

That's about it.

I wouldn't use the HTML5 doctype yet. With this doctype you're stating that your document conforms to a specification that is still a moving target. IMO: wait until the spec is finished and the validation process tied down.

Answer (score 9):

You may be interested to check out [John Resig's blog post on this topic](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/) (the founder of jQuery):

> What's nice about this new DOCTYPE,
>   especially, is that all current
>   browsers (IE, FF, Opera, Safari) will
>   look at it and switch the content into
>   standards mode - even though they
>   don't implement HTML5. This means that
>   you could start writing your web pages
>   using HTML5 today and have them last
>   for a very, very, long time.

You may also want to check out the following Stack Overflow post (August 2008):

- [Any reason not to start using the HTML 5 doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype)

Comment: Yes, I would say so. Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype

Comment: Will it really not create any problem in IE 6, and 7 and in any mobile browser. no cons of using <!DOCTYPE html> only pros,pros, pros

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. It works in every browser except IE6. There's shorter script declarations. And it's easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

It will surely break at least one old browser out there, so I recommend not using HTML 5 unless your page is actually HTML 5.

Also, XHTML and HTML 5 are not strictly compatible.

Comment: no it's compatible < /> self closing tag is also acceptable in HTML 5

Comment: Yes, but I mean is HTML 5 compatible with XHTML Strict? As far as I've seen HTML 5 is not some super-set of XHTML, they have incompatibilities.