# In the summer of 2010 is it time to start using HTML5?

Tags: html, cross-browser, doctype, semantic-markup

*I created this question as community wiki in the hope that it and its answers will be edited as the situation with HTML5 changes.*

### Time to use HTML5?

This question gets trotted out about once a year, so I might be beating a dead horse, but is it finally time (in the summer of 2010) to use HTML5 when developing a brand new web site?

#### Related HTML5 Questions on Stack Overflow

- [Is it time to start developing with HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188770/is-it-time-to-start-developing-with-html5) ('09 edition)
- [Is it time to start using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186264/is-it-time-to-start-using-html5) ('08 edition)
- [Any reason not to start using the HTML 5 doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype)
- [Is there any pros to use HTML 5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` even if i’m not using any new HTML 5 tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260252/is-there-any-pros-to-use-html-5-doctype-doctype-html-even-if-im-not-using-a)
- [Is valid HTML5 OK to use now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933241/is-valid-html5-ok-to-use-now)
- [Is it too early to use HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135580/is-it-too-early-to-use-html5)

**Edit as a follow on**

Is it a mixed bag: i.e. use these tags safely but stay away from x, y, z?

Comment: The approved spec is still not expected to be completed until somewhere in the 2021 time frame.

Comment: The big question is: WHY do you want to use HTML5? Are you talking about a particular feature? WHICH one? Or is it just because HTML5 is "cool"? Time to join the [Web 3.0 discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315/what-is-web-3-0)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I try to resist running towards things just because they are new / shiny. I am most interested in the semantic markup provided by HTML5 elements like *header*, *nav*, etc. That said I think I can refine the question to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 6):

We are far far away, see:

[When can i use...](http://caniuse.com/)

*But* you can dive into it by following:

- [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)
- [Graceful Degradation](http://www.css3.info/graceful-degradation/)

*for the moment :)*

Comment: And this is the final answer for now. Take a look a Google's source code it will probably change few times up to 2022, but it is HTML5 already.

Comment: @takeshin are they using HTML5 or just the HTML5 doctype?

Comment: @ahsteele This is what the Sarfaz's post is about. Not all the browsers support all HTML5 tags (we don't even know which tags are/will be in HTML5), but all the browsers already support the doctype.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd probably get better feedback if you clarified what you mean by 'use html5'.  That covers a lot of different functionality, some of it not even finalized.  Are you planning on using it all... or just certain pieces (like the  tag?)  Whether its a good idea to use it now is going to depend on what pieces of HTML5 you are talking about.

Comment: Modified the question to hopefully allow for *un-boxed* answers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by HTML 5.  You can use the doctype now, and many of the features are backward-compatible, so you can use them now and they will fallback gracefully.  Other tags just won't work, and so you have to be more judicious.

Answer (score 1):

Not until 2022 (if they stay on schedule).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#cite_note-techrepublicref-8

Regarding the "When can I use" link posted by Sarfraz - wow, that's an awful lot of extra work, waste of time, and consideration that could all be avoided if you just drop HTML5 and use Silverlight, Flex, or JavaFX.  Any virtual machine based solution is going to beat fighting an endless battle with browser wars.

Comment: Who’s “they”? Because as the Wikipedia article notes, the mention of 2022 in that TechRepublic interview was an estimate of when there would be two complete and interoperable implementations of HTML5, i.e. two browsers support all of HTML5 (which we don’t have for HTML 4 yet). I don’t think any browser makers have a schedule for when that’ll happen. But of course, if you’d cited the quote accurately you wouldn’t have got all that quality *snark* in there.

Comment: "They" are part of the problem huh? :) Think about it a bit more.

Comment: Is it just me or has HTML5 taken on a religious cult like status.

Comment: It's not just you. Then again, Google/Apple, two of the big drivers behind it, **do** have a cult following of their own who seem to think these companies can do no wrong, so perhaps that has something to do with it.

@Paul: W3C and anyone implementing HTML5 = they; and honestly I don't see how anything was misquoted. The overall point is, at the pace HTML5 and all non-'virtual' environments are moving, it seems like we'll all be retired by the time it catches up to Flash/Flex or Silverlight. And even then, who knows how well (and consistently) the implementation will go. Ouch!

Comment: Actually Allen, I think it's clear at this point that HTML5 is taking over king-of-all-buzzwords status from "AJAX".

Comment: @Crusader: “honestly I don't see how anything was misquoted” — 2022 was an offhand guess, not a schedule, so unless we’re using different versions of English, that‘s a misquote. Staying on definitions, the meaning of “catches up” depends on what features you think are important.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site ready to abandon half the internet?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary the case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's time! By two reasons:

1. It already works
2. It speeds up development of HTML5 compatibility

Use it with caution though! Using the simplified doctype and the new semantic markup tags will not hurt, but just do good. Using canvas and the media tags with no fallback might be a couple of years too early.

Answer (score 0):

According to readwriteweb, as of May 2010, 46% of users use browsers with html5 support. So, maybe we are over 50% now. But it really comes down to your audience - if you are targetting the general population, I would say it's a definitely too early. But if you are targetting a more tech-savvy audience, maybe not.  Of course, degrade as gracefully as possible.

Link: http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/46_of_internet_users_ready_for_html5.php

EDIT: Yes, the study mentioned in the readwriteweb reference was done by Chitika, and was based on HTML 5 video support. Chrome, Safari 3 and up, and Firefox 3.5 and up were consider "HTML 5".

Comment: "To determine a browser's HTML5 readiness, Chitika looked at the browser's ability to render HTML5 video." - That's just one feature of many in HTML5. If that's the feature you want, great. Otherwise, the measure is completely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I wish!  Wouldn't that be great!  I guess if you have a site that has a high enough demand that people will upgrade their browsers then go for it.  It seems like people are more attached to their old browsers than super glue is to fingers.