# Doctype, HTML 5

Tags: html, doctype

i have two questions:

1) was HTML5 released and if yes, when?

2) is doctype HTML 5 in use? or is it better to use one of these:
- HTML 4.01 Strict,
- HTML 4.01 Transitional,
- HTML 4.01 Frameset,
- XHTML 1.0 Strict,
- XHTML 1.0 Transitional,
- XHTML 1.0 Frameset,
- XHTML 1.1

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype

Comment: Thank you all for answers-
one more question: which doctype should i use here: http://www.ursic-ei.si/

Comment: Unless you are sending your pages with an XML MIME type, the only difference a doctype makes to a browser is whether or not to trigger Standards Mode. All of the doctypes you're considering (including the HTML5 doctype) trigger Standards Mode, so it should only matter if you're sending it as XML (or if you're using some other tools which depend on the document's strict adherence to its specified doctype).

Answer (score 7):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That's the HTML5 doctype. All modern browsers support HTML5, although feature support is not necessarily complete.

As of March 2010, the specification is in the Draft Standard state, according to the W3C timetable HTML5 should reach W3C Recommendation state by late 2010.

Nice table of HTML5 Feature support shown here:
http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/#target-selector

In my opinion, there's no reason not to use the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: That chart is nice, but a little misleading. For example, Safari on the iPhone has GeoLocation support. There must be a more detailed matrix out there.

Comment: @Frank That's true, but the chart doesn't list iPhone as a platform, only Mac/Windows…

Comment: You could say "**all** browsers support HTML5 although feature support is not necessarily complete".  NetScape 3, for example, supported the HTML5 parser but not certain elements like `<aside>` or `<style>`. :)

Answer (score 2):

A nice about this new DOCTYPE, especially, is that all current browsers (IE, FF, Opera, Safari) will look at it and switch the content into standards mode - even though they don't implement HTML5. This means that you could start writing your web pages using HTML5 today and have them last for a very, very, long time

Comment: To clarify, you can use the HTML5 doctype and be in standards mode but that does not mean you can use the HTML5 elements. Obviously, browsers must support those elements for you to use them and just using the doctype does not turn them on.

Answer (score 0):

Per a quick google search:

Question 1: yes, On January 22nd, 2008, W3C published a working draft for HTML 5.
http://www.w3schools.com/w3c/w3c_html.asp

Question 2: There are a few example html 5 sites to demonstrate what it can do, though they just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`:
http://html5demos.com/

"Note: HTML 5 is not a W3C recommendation yet! "
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

**Edit:** As Marcel Korpel said... a working draft is not an official release.

Comment: Working draft ≠ officially released... Latest draft is on http://whatwg.org/html5

Answer (score 0):

You can test some of the features of HTML5 here http://html5demos.com/ HTML5 dosen't get 'released' it is a specification that will get implemented into browsers bit by bit as time goes on. Although most popular browsers have implemented most of the standard to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest draft on http://whatwg.org/html5.

There's a section about HTML 5's [Doctype](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype) there.