# IE (7 and 8) and HTML5

Tags: html, internet-explorer, doctype

I work in a big company that runs several massive sites. All of them XHTML 1.0.

Yesterday I was arguing with the CTO because I suggested we should start using the html5 doctype. In his opinion we should stay on the "safe side" till html5 is completely out.

So supposing we're **not** implementing any new tags like <section> yet but simply adapt to the html5 doctype in order to be ready to implement new features as soon as html5 becomes final.

Are there any drawbacks? Something I should keep in mind? Any experiences?

Is there a "stable" way to work with html5 and IE 7 and 8? (we're not supporting 6 anymore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [FAQ for the HTML5 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5/faq) for more information.

Especially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype) seems to be helpful for you.

Comment: From your linked question, it seems that the spec is not yet stable. If this is the case, this is sufficient reason for the CTO to regard it as not yet stable enough.

Comment: The HTML5 specification is quite stable. The answer to that question is dated 2008!

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 works in IE7 and IE8 if you have HTMl5 reset CSS in your HTML code. You can use section/footer/header tag too if you really like to use. You can find HTML5 reset at http://html5reset.org or search in Google. If you want to fix for IE7 and IE8 for one format, you should use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`  tag with HTML5. that will fix for IE7 and IE8.