# ie7: absolute div in centered relative parent behaving strangely

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

The issue is best explained with pictures, but you can try it for yourself here:

http://pastehtml.com/view/b3y7e9uz6.html

Simply compare ie7 to (ie8 or ff or chrome).  It looks like this in modern browsers:

[image: Modern Browsers]

and like this in ie7:

[image: ie7]

What is causing it to be offcenter in ie7?

Comment: Posting the .css would be helpful.

Comment: Because you don't have a DOCTYPE declaration, the browser is running in quirks mode, you may wish to add a doctype to make browsers run in standards mode. Just in case IE7 is simply interpretting the quirks mode worse than others.

Comment: Scrap my last comment I just added a doctype and fixed the broken </head> tag and still not working in IE7... so not to do with the doctype. http://pastehtml.com/view/b3yazy3mt.html

Comment: @Mahesh, the css is in the post I linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you remove the `position: absolute` everything corrects itself, minus the red border; however, that is extremely easy to solve by applying the appropriate borders to the sides you want them on.

If you must keep the `position: absolute` add `left: 0` and that appears to correct it as well. IE7 probably requires a left/right or gets slightly messed up as it doesn't know where to position it.

Comment: Yep your problem is that you don't specify where it should be positioned. Best to add one of `top` or `bottom` and one of `left` or `right` to specify where it should position itself. Also, as @Alex Key says, you could probably do with a DOCTYPE (please use the elegant `<!DOCTYPE html>` - no reason not to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629/any-reason-not-to-start-using-the-html-5-doctype).

Comment: Good spot on the position : absolute, just had a play with that myself. Interesting stuff, I hadn't seen that before so did a little googling and came across this http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t28

Comment: @Alex Key What in particular did you come across in there?

Comment: @Akkuma. Not a huge amount on quirksmode unfortunately just a mention that there are bugs in IE7 (that I didn't know about) when positioning absolute inside a relative container. Not really the link that was interesting more that a bug / behaviour I didn't know about. Thanks for pointing it out.